# Svcutil cannot resolve wsdl metadata (content type not supported). Url works in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: jboss, svcutil.exe

Wonder if anyone can shed some light on the following.  I have the following problem...(web-service is hosted on linux/JBoss)

---

running **svcutil http://londxxx:888/tropics/TropicsWS?wsdl**

results in...

WS-Metadata Exchange Error

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service.  The client and service bindings
may be mismatched.

The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

HTTP GET Error
Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.

---

What is strange is that going to http://londxxx:888/tropics/TropicsWS?wsdl in IE works fine (i get back the wsdl xml).  Doing the same in Chrome results in a empty page.

Also, connecting to the same endpoint hosting on a different domain.  Works absolutely fine.

Any pointers on how I can diagnose this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a self-hosted service that uses the web api rest controllers.  I found the same issue where i could not access an url.  You might need to add the url.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, the webservice I'm attempting to connect to is actually hosted on linux machine (JBoss), but thanks for taking the time to answer.